# Фикстуры для sqlite в python

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, sqlite, база-данных

Для системной утилиты необходима библиотека, позволяющая легко использовать фикстуры в тестах (работа с БД sqlite3) для python. Всё, что нашел на данный момент — библиотеки, работающие с ORM. А есть ли что-нибудь, что позволит загружать первоначальные данные без использования ORM?

PS. ORM не подходит, так как необходима максимальная производительность.

PPS. Сейчас использую самописный костыль, который из JSON данных генерирует SQL запросы, но код оставляет желать лучшего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, что не стоит извращаться и запихнул фикстуры в обычные sql файлы.